# Android gallery animated views invalidate

Tags: android, animation, gallery, selection

I got this very weird problem...and it's very important to my...dead line is close...and im losing days of work on this bug.

I have gallery widget, in it i have images, and selected one is little bigger then other. I've done that with .xml scale animation.

When I click button to add another picture in it, the last selected image, but original size of it(not scaled) stays on plays where new selected item is, but somehow about it.
Like a ghost effect. I'm trying to invalidate the whole gallery, the item that is selected when i'm adding new element, after adding new element, it doesn't go away...

Please help, I'm desperate about this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out. The problem is in scale animation. 
So before notifying data I have to call view.clearAnimation();

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what your problem is, but it sounds like if you add a new element, you should let the adapter in the gallery know that you have added new data so it can redraw/refresh. Let me know if something like this works:

```
((BaseAdapter) yourGalleryView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged(); // Data has changed.
```

Comment: this.mSongIds = playListItems;
copyImagesFromArrayOfSongIntoBitmap(this.iD3);
this.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

this is base adapter. I add new element into ArrayList in copyImagesFromSongIntoBitmap method.